# From raws to column, pivot_wider mistake

Tags: r

Hi guys I have a list that looks like that :

```
Sample        Value
10            152365
10            236548
10            232547
10            145987
22            98564
22            98745
22            236547
```

And I would like to make it like this

```
10           22          
152365     98564
236548     98745 
232547     236547
145987
```

I have tried `pivot_wider`, but, since I have over 100'000 values it give me the mistake that some identical values are found and thus cannot work, wheras the `spread` just simply freeze...
Can you help me?

Thanks
Lore

Comment: `split(data$Value, data$Sample)` is what you want?

Comment: You can't have a data frame in R with different column lengths. You can get a `list` that is approximately in the format you want by doing `split(df$Value, df$Sample)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the blank under `22` can be `NA`, this works:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
quux %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(rn, names_from = "Sample", values_from = "Value") %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#     `10`   `22`
#    <int>  <int>
# 1 152365  98564
# 2 236548  98745
# 3 232547 236547
# 4 145987     NA
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Sample = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 22L, 22L, 22L), Value = c(152365L, 236548L, 232547L, 145987L, 98564L, 98745L, 236547L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```